# Is possible set more Line Dasharray for one polyline in mapbox

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapbox

Im using Naxam Mapbox in my Xamarin Forms project. I need to set more LineDasharray styled for one polyline (part of polyline is full line and the rest is dotted).

All features has string property "isDottedLine"
I've tried this:

```
        LineDasharray = Expression.SwitchCase
        (
            Expression.Eq(Expression.ToString(Expression.Get("isDottedLine")), Expression.ToString("true")), Expression.Literal(new[] { 0.1f, 1.5f }), // dotted line
            Expression.Literal(new[] { 1f, 0f })// full line
        ),
```

But it does not work. Whole polyline is visible as full line. Is any problem in my code or it is not possible to set more LineDasharray style for one polyline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the Mapbox does not support data-driven styling for line-dasharray.
Documentation is [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-line-line-dasharray).